# Multithreaded Observer in Java - preserve proper order

Tags: java, multithreading, observers

I am implementing something that I would call "Observable Set". It is just a normal set, but it can have some observers that are notified about adding new elements.

What is important for me, is that elements may be added from many threads at time, and also there are many observing threads. I hold Observers in CopyOnWriteArrayList (it is thread-safe).  The key point is to inform observers about adding elements in way, that informing order for each of observers is the same as order of adding elements.

What is best approach?

The most naive one is to put adding and informing in "synchronized" block. But i believe it can be slow etc.

Second I've tried was to just add element to set, and add it to "informing queue". With each addition of element it was checked whether informing is turned on. If not, it was started until the queue was empty. It was working quite OK but i was afraid that it wasn't nice approach.

The last that I've implemented, i would call as "informing threads". With adding observers, each observer has it's own "informing thread" created. That thread runs in background and checks if it's at end of global "informing queue". If it isn't it informs specific thread about new elements. However I've problems with synchronization, and while(true) loop. I don't know how to set condition to end thread. The next problem I noticed when writing it, is that every new thread will be informed from beginning... It's not good.

I hope I have described everything quite well. If not, please let me know, i will try to fix it. 
What is best way to accomplish this task?
Thanks!

Comment: "The most naive one is to put adding and informing in "synchronized" block. But i believe it can be slow etc." Have you actually tried it to see if it is slow?

Comment: @Sizik is right.  always go with simplicity until you know the optimization is required.

Comment: Well, i've tried it :) But it is not allowed by person who I am doing it for. It will be slow, because when adding you would have to wait for all observers to be informed in order to add next element, while it can be done by other thread for example at the same time..

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution could be improved to use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html): with it you don't need to check whether "informing is turned on", you just call take(), and it will wait for something to appear in the queue.

You could also look into the [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) project. It is somewhat complex, but it has lots of features you might need.

> It extends the observer pattern to support sequences of data/events and adds operators that allow you to compose sequences together declaratively while abstracting away concerns about things like low-level threading, synchronization, thread-safety and concurrent data structures.

Comment: Thanks for idea. It may also improve 3rd solution.